# Tree Boosting performance in overfitted models

Tags: large-data, model-evaluation, boosting

Working with datasets that have millions of examples and thousands of available features, it's my experience that gradient boosted trees have a plateau in validation performance, after which overfitting happens. However,  it's common to see small gains in validation performance long after the overfitting starts (talking about 1000 selected features). I also noticed and read how boosting is robust against increases in validation error due to overfitting - it has a plateau but rarely goes up again in the overfitted model.

Can anyone properly explain this recurrence of small gains? Given near-infinite computing resources, is it reasonable to use highly overfitted models to capture the (possible) extra performance?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean.  An overfitted model by definition has captured complexity in the training data that does not generalize to the testing data.  So I don't understand what you mean by an overfitted model gaining validation performance, that's exactly what overfitting is not.

Comment: I drew a quick sketch in paint to illustrate https://i.imgur.com/ohnqBNX.jpg

Comment: Yup, that picture is pretty standard for a boosted model.  But it does *not* show any overfitting.